# Why does boost::shared_ptr bother with atomic reference counting when it's not thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, shared-ptr, atomicreference

This is more of a curiosity question, but as boost::shared_ptr is not thread-safe, why would it then bother using atomic reference counting?  Since the destructor is not safe to use across threads, I'm failing to see the point.

For example, if you pass a copy of the shared_ptr to a thread, it will always destruct, at least when the thread ends at the very latest.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're misunderstanding the thread safety limitations of shared pointers. A shared pointer itself is not thread safe in the sense that you don't want to manipulate the same shared pointer in two different threads. However, it is almost never safe to manipulate the same object in two different threads at the same time and that is not thread safe with most objects.

It *is* perfectly thread-safe to manipulate two different shared pointers in two different threads, even if they're pointers to the same object.

For example, a thread can create an object and a shared pointer to it. Then it can create another shared pointer to that same object. Then one thread can manipulate the first shared pointer and another thread can manipulate the second shared pointer. When the last of the two shared pointers (and any additional copies made) goes away, the object will get destroyed.

Comment: Take this example from the boost documentation at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety

// thread A 
p3 = p2; // reads p2, writes p3 
// thread B 
// p2 goes out of scope: undefined, the destructor is considered a "write access"

Comment: In your cited example, the two threads are accessing the *same* shared pointer, `p2`. Yes, two threads should not be using the same shared pointer without synchronization, just as they shouldn't be using the same string or the same map. However, it is perfectly fine for two threads to use two different shared pointers, even if they both point to the same object.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I was picturing a case where the ref count reached zero while another reference was created, but then realized that that wasn't possible.  Thanks for your comments.